# Ember.js - how to 'get' computed properties

Tags: ember.js

I have successfully created and bound computed properties, but how can I get at them manually in other parts of my code?

```
App.Test = Ember.Object.extend(
   value: "1"
   unit: "INCH"

   display: (->
     value = this.get('value')
     unit = this.get('unit')
     return "#{value} #{unit}"
   ).property('value', 'unit')
)
```

How do I call the 'display' method in, say, a controller? The following shows what I thought would work...

```
myTest = App.Test.create()
displayValue1 = myTest.get('display')
displayValue2 = myTest.display()
```

displayValue1 just returns me an object, not a string. displayValue2 throws a 'no function found" error. So how do I access this property other than a binding?

Comment: what do you see when you inspect the object from `displayValue1`? That should return the string, it looks right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider computed properties as properties, not method. Even if they contains a little bit of logic, they really are properties, so you should never call them as a method.

You can access them using the classic `Ember.get` method, as you can see below:

```
MyApp.myObject = Ember.Object.create({
    name: "foo",
    surname: "bar",
    aComputedProperty: function() {
        return this.get('name') + ' ' + this.get('surname');
    }.property('name', 'surname')
});

MyApp.myObject.get('aComputedProperty'); // => 'foo bar'
```

You can try this code [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8v3k/).

Comment: So, this is what I thought should work, so there must be something else weird going on in my code. When I bind to the property, I get a string, but when I call "get" I don't... at least I know in theory I'm doing it right, thanks.